# bash: How to add array elements to command?

Tags: arrays, bash, curl

I got values in a file that needs to read and added to a command. This is my failing solution...

```
for arrayValue in "${fileArray[@]}"
do
    curl -s --user "${arrayValue[0]}:${arrayValue[1]}" "https://dyndns.loopia.se?hostname=$arrayValue
done
```

The file is like this:

```
username
password
domain
domain
...
```

Reading from the file is no problem, the problem is how to add them to the curl command.

Comment: You are filling `fileArray=( < yourfile )`? Show the output of `declare -p fileArray`. (before the loop). And, what is the end your `curl` command, e.g. `"https://dyndns.loopia.se?hostname=$arrayValue..."`?

Comment: Is the user name and the password in the same array as the other data?

Comment: I didn't ask about reading the file, I asked (1) "How are you filling your array?" and (2) "What is the content of your array immediately prior to your loop?"

Comment: `curl -s --user "${arrayValue[0]}:${arrayValue[1]}"` should be `curl -s --user "${fileArray[0]}:${fileArray[1]}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your array contains the user name and password in the first two elements, and you want to avoid looping over those, try

```
for arrayValue in "${fileArray[@]:2}"
do
    curl -s --user "${fileArray[0]}:${fileArray[1]}" "https://dyndns.loopia.se?hostname=$arrayValue"
done
```

Notice how `arrayValue` refers to the current element out of `fileArray`.  It is not an array, so the references to `${arrayValue[0]}` and `${arrayValue[1]}` in your attempt were not valid.

Also notice how we loop over the array elements starting from the third with the `:2` suffix. (Array indexing is zero-based, so the index `2` refers to the third element.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no blank character (space, CR...) in the hostname, you could also get rid of the `for` loop by using `printf`:

```
printf -v url "https://dyndns.loopia.se?hostname=${fileArray[@]:2}"
```

Note the `:2` that gets all array elements except the 2 first ones.

Since `curl` accepts several URL, you can simple use:

```
curl -s --user "${fileArray[0]}:${fileArray[1]}" $url
```